# Как при генерации отчета pytest allure (json) добавить свой status?

Tags: python, pytest, allure

Мне необходимо получиться статус "unknown" при генерации отчета allure pytest (python). Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

requirements.txt

```
pytest==7.3.1
allure-pytest==2.13.2
```

test_results.py

```
import pytest
import allure

def test_exp_fail():
    pytest.fail('FAIL !!!')
def test_exp_skiped():
    pytest.skip('SKIPED !!!')
def test_exp_warning():
    pytest.warns('WARNING !!!')
def test_exp_unknown():
    Здесь необходиму вернуть UNKNOWN
```

Отчет allure (ключивая часть по test_exp_unknown)

```
{
    "name": "test_exp_unknown",
     "status": "unknown",
     ...
}
```

pytest.ini

```
addopts = -v --alluredir=./logs/
```